# Routing all traffic via Raspberry Pi with OpenVPN on a OpenWRT Briged AP

Tags: networking, routing, openvpn, raspberry-pi, openwrt

I want to route all traffic on my OpenWRT router via my Raspberry Pi that has a OpenVPN client connection.

I have a simple setup:

```
+-------------------+            +---------------+
|                   |  Connected |               |
|     ISP MODEM     +------------+OpenWRT Router |
|    192.168.1.1    | to lan port| 192.168.1.2   |
+-------------------+            +--+-----------++
                                    |           |
                                    |           |
                                    |           |
                             +------+-------+   |  +-------------------+
                             | Raspberry Pi |   |  | All other devices |
                             | with OpenVPN |   +--+ connected via WiFi|
                             | 192.168.1.3  |      |    192.168.1.*    |
                             +--------------+      +-------------------+
```

I literally followed [this guide to setup a bridged AP on OpenWRT](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/recipes/bridgedap) and [this tutorial to setup OpenVPN on my Raspberry Pi](https://gist.github.com/superjamie/ac55b6d2c080582a3e64). I believe that the settings on the Raspberry Pi are correct.

I tried to change the default gateway as following on my OpenWRT router:

```
root@OpenWrt:~# ip route del default
root@OpenWrt:~# ip route add default via 192.168.1.3
root@OpenWrt:~# route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.1.3     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 br-lan
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br-lan
```

On my router I see that this worked because it now has an IP of the VPN provider

```
root@OpenWrt:~# wget -qO- http://canihazip.com/s
46.166.186.213
```

However on all my devices that are connected to the OpenWRT router's WiFi or cable, I still get my old ISP's IP.

I realize that there are many similar questions here, however non off the solutions worked for me. I know little about networks and start to think that what I want is not possible with a bridged AP.

Comment: Read this article https://www.sitepoint.com/setting-up-a-home-vpn-using-your-raspberry-pi/

Comment: I think it wouldn't work. You have to add one more interface on raspberry pi and put it in between ISP modem and AP router. Why you don't use openWRT as openVPN client in router mode? AFAIK openWRT supported it

Comment: @narzan thanks for the link, but that guide helps in setting up a VPN server, which I already have (because I pay for it).

Comment: "To access the VPN from other computers and devices on the network, it will need a client that these devices can connect through" < are you sure you checked this step!

Comment: @Alex thanks for your comment, how sure are you about it not being possible? I have tried setting up OpenVPN on the router, but I probably ran into the same problem: I have it set up as a bridged AP. Should I set it up as a Routed AP or Routed Client or something else?

Comment: @narzan Yes, set openWRT as a router, connect WAN port to ISP modem, change DHCP range on LAN side to something different from 192.168.1.0/24 then openVPN on openWRT should drive all LAN connections over OpenVPN channel.

Comment: @Alex thanks a lot. Would you perhaps know what I should search for in order to setup my OpenWRT as router? When I search for it I keep finding guides that explain how to get a Routed Client or something else. (I know how to setup the OpenVPN part)

Comment: I found out why it didn't work. I accidentally still had a gateway specified. Everything is setup now! Thanks again.

Comment: @johnbaltis I suggest you to answer and accept your question with changes you did, so it would be useful for somebody else and for you too as tech notes. It absolutely Ok with policy on this site and even encouraged to do that

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to do this with a bridged access point set-up.

And to do this you don't need the Raspberry Pi at all.

Make the following setup:

```
+-------------------+            +---------------+
|                   |  Connected |               |
|     ISP MODEM     +------------+OpenWRT Router |
|    192.168.1.1    | to wan port| 192.168.2.1   |
+-------------------+            +-------+-------+
                                         |
                                         |
                                         |
                              +----------+--------+
                              | All other devices |
                              | connected via WiFi|
                              |    192.168.2.*    |
                              +-------------------+
```

On a router with default settings:

1. Open `/etc/config/network` and find `config interface 'lan'`.
2. There you change `option ipaddr '192.168.1.1'` to `option ipaddr '192.168.2.1'`.
3. Then follow a guide to set-up OpenVPN on the OpenWRT router. I used [this guide on GitHub](https://github.com/basnijholt/privateinternetaccess-on-openwrt/) which is for the Private Internet Access provider, but it should apply to all providers that support OpenVPN. Note that in the tutorial I link, they use `192.168.1.1`, instead you should now use `192.168.2.1`.